# Question tags in the list don't match tags of the question when opened

Tags: bug, tags

In the question list (main SO page by default) the question

[image]

contains a bunch of php-related tags.

While it actually is not about php and in fact has never had those tags set: [How to directly get the father node?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52472518/251311)

Comment: The question was probably edited during the 5-minute grace period. The homepage doesn't show live updates (unlike most other question lists), so there was no way for you to see that it had been changed.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I coincidentally opened a question within few seconds after it was created and it was like that already. If it was edited the OP must have been super quick

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: The list is nearly always *a little* outdated. The question may already be answered, downvoted, closed, edited (including title and tags).. Could you confirm wrong tags after refreshing the list few minutes later?

Comment: @Sinatr what does "a little outdated" mean given that I believe those tags _never_ were assigned to that question?